# How to handle metadatas in the Chromium FFmpegDecodingLoop with custom Avfilter?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, chromium

I'm trying to add a deinterlacing filter to the decoding loop of ffmpeg in Chromium by using a custom avFilter.

**What I have now:**
I made alll the changes required for ffmpeg to work with the `yadif` filter.
I created an avFilter graph:

```
void FFmpegDecodingLoop::InitFilterGraph(AVFrame *frame) {
    if (media_log_) MEDIA_LOG(DEBUG, media_log_) << "entering InitFilterGraph : " << filter_initialised;
    if (filter_initialised) return;

    int result;

    const AVFilter *buffer_src   = avfilter_get_by_name("buffer");
    const AVFilter *buffer_sink  = avfilter_get_by_name("buffersink");
    AVFilterInOut *inputs  = avfilter_inout_alloc();
    AVFilterInOut *outputs = avfilter_inout_alloc();

    AVCodecContext *ctx = context_;
    char args[512];

    int frame_fix = 0; // fix bad width on some streams
    if (frame->width < 704) frame_fix = 2;
    else if (frame->width > 704) frame_fix = -16;

    snprintf(args, sizeof(args),
         "video_size=%dx%d:pix_fmt=%d:time_base=%d/%d:pixel_aspect=%d/%d",
         frame->width + frame_fix,
         frame->height,
         frame->format,// ctx->pix_fmt,
         ctx->time_base.num,
         ctx->time_base.den,
         ctx->sample_aspect_ratio.num,
         ctx->sample_aspect_ratio.den);

    const char *description = "yadif";

    filter_graph = avfilter_graph_alloc();
    if (media_log_) MEDIA_LOG(DEBUG, media_log_) << "Filter graph - args : " << args;
    result = avfilter_graph_create_filter(&buffersrc_ctx_, buffer_src, "in", args, NULL, filter_graph);
    if (result < 0) {
        if (media_log_) MEDIA_LOG(ERROR, media_log_) << "Filter graph - Unable to create buffer source : " << result;
        return;
    }

    AVBufferSinkParams *params = av_buffersink_params_alloc();
    enum AVPixelFormat pix_fmts[] = { AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P9, AV_PIX_FMT_NONE };

    params->pixel_fmts = pix_fmts;
    result = avfilter_graph_create_filter(&buffersink_ctx_, buffer_sink, "out", NULL, params, filter_graph);
    av_free(params);
    if (result < 0) {
        if (media_log_) MEDIA_LOG(ERROR, media_log_) << "Filter graph - Unable to create buffer sink";
        return;
    }

    inputs->name        = av_strdup("out");
    inputs->filter_ctx  = buffersink_ctx_;
    inputs->pad_idx     = 0;
    inputs->next        = NULL;

    outputs->name       = av_strdup("in");
    outputs->filter_ctx = buffersrc_ctx_;
    outputs->pad_idx    = 0;
    outputs->next       = NULL;


    result = avfilter_graph_parse_ptr(filter_graph, description, &inputs, &outputs, NULL);
    if (result < 0 && media_log_) MEDIA_LOG(ERROR, media_log_) << "Filter graph - avfilter_graph_parse_ptr ERROR : " << result;

    result = avfilter_graph_config(filter_graph, NULL);
    if (result < 0 && media_log_) MEDIA_LOG(ERROR, media_log_) << "Filter graph - avfilter_graph_config error";

    filter_initialised = true;
}
```

And when I receive the frame, depending on the fact it's interlaced or not, I send it to the avFilter graph or straight to the `frame_ready_cb`.

```
    ...
    bool frame_processing_success = false;
    if (!frame_.get()->interlaced_frame) {     // not interlaced
          if (media_log_) MEDIA_LOG(DEBUG, media_log_) << "Detected not interlaced video frame";
          frame_processing_success = frame_ready_cb.Run(frame_.get());
    } else {
      if (media_log_) MEDIA_LOG(DEBUG, media_log_) << "Detected interlaced video frame" << frame_.get()->metadata;

      if (!filter_initialised) {
        this->InitFilterGraph(frame_.get());
        if (media_log_) MEDIA_LOG(DEBUG, media_log_) << "Media filter ok";
      } 

      if (av_buffersrc_add_frame_flags(buffersrc_ctx_, frame_.get(), AV_BUFFERSRC_FLAG_KEEP_REF) < 0) {
        if (!continue_on_decoding_errors_)
          return DecodeStatus::kDecodeFrameFailed;
        decoder_error = true;
        continue;
      }

      while (true) {
        const int ret = av_buffersink_get_frame(buffersink_ctx_, filter_frame_.get());
        if (media_log_) MEDIA_LOG(DEBUG, media_log_) << "ret = " << ret;
        if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF){
          if (media_log_) MEDIA_LOG(DEBUG, media_log_) << "ret error but waiting for more frames" << ret;
          frame_processing_success = true;
          if (media_log_) MEDIA_LOG(DEBUG, media_log_) << "ret error but waitning for more frames ; filter description = " << buffersink_ctx_->filter->description;
          break;
        }
        
        if (ret < 0) {
          if (!continue_on_decoding_errors_)
            return DecodeStatus::kDecodeFrameFailed;
          decoder_error = true;
          frame_processing_success = true;
          break;
        }
        frame_processing_success = frame_ready_cb.Run(filter_frame_.get());
        if (media_log_) MEDIA_LOG(DEBUG, media_log_) << "producing deinterlaced frame : " << frame_processing_success;
        av_frame_unref(filter_frame_.get());
      }
    }
    av_frame_unref(frame_.get());
    if (!frame_processing_success)
      return DecodeStatus::kFrameProcessingFailed;
}
```

This seems to work, I can send frames to the avFilter and get them back but I'm having an issue with the metadas (it seems).

**The issue:**
When I get a frame from the avFilter (`av_buffersink_get_frame(buffersink_ctx_, filter_frame_.get())`) and send it to the frame ready callback I have this kind of errors :

```
    [36723:38755:0914/105148.322600:FATAL:values.cc(516)] Check failed: is_dict(). 
0   libbase.dylib                       0x00000001052febff base::debug::CollectStackTrace(void**, unsigned long) + 31
1   libbase.dylib                       0x0000000104f9717b base::debug::StackTrace::StackTrace(unsigned long) + 75
2   libbase.dylib                       0x0000000104f971fd base::debug::StackTrace::StackTrace(unsigned long) + 29
3   libbase.dylib                       0x0000000104f971d8 base::debug::StackTrace::StackTrace() + 40
4   libbase.dylib                       0x0000000104fe4897 logging::LogMessage::~LogMessage() + 183
5   libbase.dylib                       0x0000000104fe3515 logging::LogMessage::~LogMessage() + 21
6   libbase.dylib                       0x00000001052df4dc base::Value::SetKey(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&&, base::Value&&) + 188
7   libmedia.dylib                      0x000000010eda0dea media::VideoFrameMetadata::SetBoolean(media::VideoFrameMetadata::Key, bool) + 90
8   libmedia.dylib                      0x000000010efb6943 media::FFmpegVideoDecoder::OnNewFrame(AVFrame*) + 403
9   libmedia.dylib                      0x000000010efb716b bool base::internal::FunctorTraits<bool (media::FFmpegVideoDecoder::*)(AVFrame*), void>::Invoke<bool (media::FFmpegVideoDecoder::*)(AVFrame*), media::FFmpegVideoDecoder*, AVFrame*>(bool (media::FFmpegVideoDecoder::*)(AVFrame*), media::FFmpegVideoDecoder*&&, AVFrame*&&) + 155
10  libmedia.dylib                      0x000000010efb7046 bool base::internal::InvokeHelper<false, bool>::MakeItSo<bool (media::FFmpegVideoDecoder::* const&)(AVFrame*), media::FFmpegVideoDecoder*, AVFrame*>(bool (media::FFmpegVideoDecoder::* const&)(AVFrame*), media::FFmpegVideoDecoder*&&, AVFrame*&&) + 102
11  libmedia.dylib                      0x000000010efb6fa5 bool base::internal::Invoker<base::internal::BindState<bool (media::FFmpegVideoDecoder::*)(AVFrame*), base::internal::UnretainedWrapper<media::FFmpegVideoDecoder> >, bool (AVFrame*)>::RunImpl<bool (media::FFmpegVideoDecoder::* const&)(AVFrame*), std::__1::tuple<base::internal::UnretainedWrapper<media::FFmpegVideoDecoder> > const&, 0ul>(bool (media::FFmpegVideoDecoder::* const&)(AVFrame*), std::__1::tuple<base::internal::UnretainedWrapper<media::FFmpegVideoDecoder> > const&, std::__1::integer_sequence<unsigned long, 0ul>, AVFrame*&&) + 101
12  libmedia.dylib                      0x000000010efb6f0a base::internal::Invoker<base::internal::BindState<bool (media::FFmpegVideoDecoder::*)(AVFrame*), base::internal::UnretainedWrapper<media::FFmpegVideoDecoder> >, bool (AVFrame*)>::Run(base::internal::BindStateBase*, AVFrame*) + 106
13  libmedia.dylib                      0x000000010f127101 base::RepeatingCallback<bool (AVFrame*)>::Run(AVFrame*) const & + 113
14  libmedia.dylib                      0x000000010f126e70 media::FFmpegDecodingLoop::DecodePacket(AVPacket const*, base::RepeatingCallback<bool (AVFrame*)>) + 2528
```

So the error is in `FFmpegVideoDecoder::OnNewFrame` when it calls `media::VideoFrameMetadata::SetBoolean`.
I get the same kind of errors when `void VideoFrameMetadata::SetTimeTicks` gets called.

So obviously I have an issue with the metadatas of the video frame I get back from the avFilter which has just a `yadif` filter.

Is there something I missed with the metadas or otherwise ?